# Возникает ошибка в QT, при образовании типов, как можно её пофиксить?

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    chartLayout[0] = new QGridLayout(ui->widget_graph_0);
    //chartLayout[0]
    //chartLayout[1] = new QGridLayout(ui->widget_graph_1);
   // chartLayout[2] = new QGridLayout(ui->widget_graph_2);


    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_GRAPH; i++)
    {

        base_chart[i] = new QChart();
        chart[i] = new QChartView(base_chart[i]);
        chartLayout[i]->addWidget(chart[i],0,0);
        pGraph[i] = new QLineSeries;

        axesX[i] = new QValueAxis;
        axesX[i]->setRange(0,mX);
        axesX[i]->setTickCount(5);
        axesX[i]->setMinorTickCount(1);
        axesX[i]->setLabelFormat("%i");



        axesY[i] = new QValueAxis;
        axesY[i]->setRange(0,8388608);
        axesY[i]->setTickCount(11);
        axesY[i]->setMinorTickCount(1);
        axesY[i]->setLabelFormat("%.i");

        axesX[i]->setLabelsVisible(false);
        axesY[i]->setLabelsVisible(false);

       // axisX[i]->setObjectName(false);

        base_chart[i]->addSeries(pGraph[i]);
      '  base_chart[i]->addAxis(axesX[i],pGraph[i]);  // Ошибка 1
        base_chart[i]->addAxis(axesY[i],pGraph[i]); '  // Ошибка 2 
    }


    pAdcDev = new CAdcDev;

    QMetaObject::Connection Res;
    Res=connect(pAdcDev, SIGNAL(AdcDataReady(CAdcDev::AdcDataFile)), this, SLOT(AdcDataHandle(CAdcDev::AdcDataFile)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    if (!Res)
        throw;

    pAdcDev->Begin();
    pAdcDev->Ads131Start();

}



void MainWindow::AdcDataHandle(CAdcDev::AdcDataFile adc_data)
{
    static char buffer[40];
    static int idx = 0;
    static int error = 0;
    int i,j;

    idx_sample.idx_byte[3] = 0;
    adc_sample.adc_sample_byte[3] = 0;

    for(j = 0; j < MAX_GRAPH; j++) pGraph[j]->clear();

    for(i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        idx_sample.idx_byte[0] = adc_data.adc_data[i].index[0];
        idx_sample.idx_byte[1] = adc_data.adc_data[i].index[1];
        idx_sample.idx_byte[2] = adc_data.adc_data[i].index[2];

        if(idx_sample.idx_word != idx++)
            // сравнение типов int и uint вызывает ошибку
        {  error++;
           idx = idx_sample.idx_word;
        }

        for(j = 0; j < MAX_GRAPH; j++)
        {
            adc_sample.adc_sample_byte[2] = adc_data.adc_data[i].channel[j][0];
            adc_sample.adc_sample_byte[1] = adc_data.adc_data[i].channel[j][1];
            adc_sample.adc_sample_byte[0] = adc_data.adc_data[i].channel[j][2];

            if((adc_sample.adc_sample_word & 0x800000) == 0x800000)
            {
               adc_sample.adc_sample_word |= 0xff000000;
               adc_sample.adc_sample_word ^= 0xffffffff; // ??? ???????? ?? ?????? ????????? !!!
            }

            *pGraph[j] << QPoint(i,adc_sample.adc_sample_word);
        }

    }

    sprintf(buffer,"%d / %d ",idx_sample.idx_word,error);
    ui->textBrowser->append(buffer);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Сама ошибка:

```
mainwindow.cpp:44:41: error: no viable conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'Qt::Alignment' (aka 'QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>')
qflags.h:89:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'const QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag> &' for 1st argument
qflags.h:89:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag> &&' for 1st argument
qflags.h:118:29: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'Qt::AlignmentFlag' for 1st argument
qflags.h:119:29: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>::Zero' (aka 'int (QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>::Private::*)') for 1st argument
qflags.h:120:29: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'QFlag' for 1st argument
qflags.h:122:29: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to 'std::initializer_list<AlignmentFlag>' for 1st argument
qchart.h:112:53: note: passing argument to parameter 'alignment' here
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#addAxis

Comment: Спасибо, но я не догоняю к сожалению, как это преобразовать в код. 
Если я правильно понимаю void QChart::addAxis(QAbstractAxis *axis, Qt::Alignment alignment)
то здесь  передача значений в функцию, а вот как дальше сделать, моя мысль не идёт. 
Объясните пожалуйста, если несложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QChart::AddAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchart.html#addAxis)

Из документации:

> Adds the axis `axis` to the chart aligned as specified by `alignment`. The
> chart takes the ownership of the axis.

Перевод:

> Метод добавляет ось `axis` к графику, выравнивая его в соответствии с
> аргументом `alignment`. Объект графика берет объект оси в управление
> (прим.: то есть, отвечает за его удаление после работы).

Собственно, в вашем вызове `base_chart[i]->addAxis(axesX[i], pGraph[i]);` второй аргумент должен быть типа `Qt::Alignment`, например `Qt::AlignCenter` о чем и сигнализирует ошибка:

> error: no viable conversion from 'QtCharts::QLineSeries *' to
> 'Qt::Alignment' (aka 'QFlags<Qt::AlignmentFlag>')

Перевод:

> Ошибка: нет подходящего преобразования из типа `QtCharts::QLineSeries`
> в `Qt::Alignment`